# Return in a recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm having a problem with the result of this problem, apparently it only returns the first use case, where am I going wrong?

**Problem:**

Create a recursive function that takes a string as input and also its length. This function should return how many times the character 'x' appears in the string.

**Prohibited**

The first line in the input contains the number n of test cases. Next, n lines occur, each containing a string with a maximum length of 5000 characters.

**Exit**

The output consists of n lines, each containing an integer that indicates the number of times the letter 'x' occurs in the input. All strings are written in lowercase.

**Example**

Prohibited:

```
3
open cadabra
chess taxi bacaxi rate box pulls sandpaper
syrup xxx
```

Expected Return:

```
0
7
4
```

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5000

int ocorrencias(char palavra[], char letra, int i) {
    if (palavra[i] == '\0') return 0;
    return (letra == palavra[i]) + ocorrencias(palavra, letra, i + 1);
}

int main() {
    char palavra[MAX];
    char letra = 'x';
    int i,j,n;
    int re[MAX];

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s", palavra);
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        re[j] = ocorrencias(palavra, letra, 0);
    }

    printf("%d \n",re[j]);
}
```

Comment: print the result *inside* of the loop.

Comment: I tried, passed 2 test cases and passed two words chi and chess and the return was 1 and 1

Comment: That's when you submit to a *debugger*. And if your real code has the print inside the loop, so too should the code you posted here, along with input *and* expected-vs-actual results for the specific cases you're failing. Fyi, `scanf("%s", palavra);` is *not* going to work if you're attempting to read multi-word, whitespace separated strings on a single line of text. That will read *one* string (one word) after skipping any leading whitespace. The test says per-**line**.  Investigate `fgets` (fyi,you don't need it to solve this problem: basically hunt-for-newline n-times whilst counting 'x'.)

Comment: Your input and expected output doesn't  seem to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ocorrencias()` works but doesn't satisfy your requirement that it has to accept a length of the string.
2. `scanf("%d", ...)` will leave the trailing newline so append a space to the format string to flush it.
3. It's better to use `fgets()` to read a string with spaces.  It doesn't matter here but `fgets()` will return a string with a newline.
4. `re` should hold `n` results (1 per string) not MAX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 5000

int ocorrencias(const char *palavra, size_t len) {
    return len ?
        ('x' == *palavra) + ocorrencias(palavra + 1, len - 1) :
        0;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if(scanf("%d ", &n) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char palavra[MAX];
    int re[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        fgets(palavra, MAX, stdin);
        re[i] = ocorrencias(palavra, strlen(palavra));
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n", re[i]);
    }
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
3
open cadabra
chess taxi bacaxi rate box pulls sandpaper
syrup xxx
0
3
3
```